# AngularJS ng-hide/show label/button if length(description) < 20

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show, ng-hide, angularjs-ng-if

I need to show/hide label if length(description) < one row. Code is working ok, but if length < one row, label isn't hide. How to hide/show label?

If [[ demandAd.description ]] less than one line or less than one row(or length < 100), I need to hide label because it doesn't have a function at that time

```html
<div class="demand">
    <p class="demand-ad-time">[[demandAd.createdAt | date:"dd.MM.yyyy."]]</p>
    <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="demandAd[[ demandAd.id ]]" />
    <p>[[ demandAd.description ]]</p>
    <label for="demandAd[[ demandAd.id ]]" class="read-more-trigger"></label>
    <hr>
    <div class="demand-chips">
        <div class="demand-chip" ng-repeat="demandAdLabel in demandAd.labelsWithPlaces track by $index">[[ demandAdLabel ]]</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you rewrite? I'm afraid I cannot understand what you exactly want?

Comment: if [[ demandAd.description ]] less than one line or less than one line, I need to hide
    <label for="demandAd[[ demandAd.id ]]" class="read-more-trigger"></label>
because it doesn't have a function at that time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I understand correctly, you want to hide a label when the text length is shorter than 100. You can compare the text length within `ng-hide`

```
<body ng-app="">

Hide base on text length: <input type="text" ng-model="myVar">

<div ng-hide="myVar.length >= 3">
<label>Hide when length >= than 3</label>
</div>

</body>
```

Here is a live sample code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/vHVXyNCTzPiuVwq2fyOG?p=preview

Comment: No problem, happy coding :)